# A mathcounts question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

The question is this.

> There are $240$ pairs of numbers such as $(7,5318)$ or $(17,358)$ that can be formed using each of the digits $1$, $3$, $5$, $7$ and $8$ exactly once. What is the largest possible product of two such numbers?

Why wouldn't the answer be $87531 \times 87513$?

The answer key says $62333$.

This is a *Mathcounts* problem, from the $2011-2012$ handbook.

Comment: Because each digit is used twice in $\{87531, 87513\}$?

Comment: How would I get 62333 then? The biggest I can get is 831 * 75.

Comment: Notice $62333=83\cdot 751$

Comment: You get already the optimum quite fast , if you permute over the possible subsets of the digits for one of the numbers, this requires only $16$ steps (using the symmetry in the problem) because it is clear that the optimum must be formed from two numbers with decreasing digits. Perhaps we can still improve this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by realising that the answer must be one of the following:

8??? X 7

7??? X 8

8?? X 7?

7?? X 8?

These are all going to give a value greater than 56000.

Then consider how to replace the ???: must be with 531 in that order.

It’s less obvious what to do with the others. There are three possibilities for the single ? and then the ?? must be the other two digits in decreasing order.

So your candidates are:

8531 X 7

7532 X 8

853 X 71

851 X 73

831 X 75

753 X 81

751 X 83

731 X 85

Answer (score 0):

No digits can be repeated, so 87531 * 87513 is not an option. Look for a two digit $*$ 3 digit number combination